# Calling an async function from within another, using a borrowed argument passed through

Tags: rust, async-await

I am trying to pass an async function into another async function, and call it inside, passing on a borrowed argument, like this:

```rust
use std::{future::Future, time::Duration};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    takes_callback("foo", callback).await.expect("ERROR")
}

async fn callback(s: &str) -> Result<(), ()> {
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    Ok(())
}

async fn takes_callback<F, R>(s: &str, callback: F) -> Result<(), ()>
where
    F: FnOnce(&str) -> R,
    R: Future<Output = Result<(), ()>>,
{
    callback(s).await
}
```

I get this compile error:

```
$ cargo check
    Checking async_callback v0.1.0 (/home/andy/Desktop/async_callback)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:5:5
   |
5  |     takes_callback("foo", callback).await.expect("ERROR")
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected opaque type `impl for<'a> Future<Output = Result<(), ()>>`
              found opaque type `impl Future<Output = Result<(), ()>>`
   = help: consider `await`ing on both `Future`s
   = note: distinct uses of `impl Trait` result in different opaque types
note: the lifetime requirement is introduced here
  --> src/main.rs:15:24
   |
15 |     F: FnOnce(&str) -> R,
   |                        ^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `async_callback` (bin "async_callback") due to previous error
```

It works fine if I remove the `s` argument, so I think I understand that the problem is to do with the lifetime of `s` in the returned `Future`.

Please could you explain what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I pressed submit I figured it out. I need to specify that the reference passed in to `F` has the same lifetime as the reference passed into `takes_callback`, so I need to change `takes_callback` to specify that by adding a `'a` generic lifetime parameter, and adding it to the `s` argument, and the argument to `F`:

```rust
async fn takes_callback<'a, F, R>(s: &'a str, callback: F) -> Result<(), ()>
where
    F: FnOnce(&'a str) -> R,
    R: Future<Output = Result<(), ()>>,
{
    callback(s).await
}
```